# Mikro ORM unique decorator is not being enforced when

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, relation, mikro-orm

Using this entity:

```
@Entity()
@Unique({ properties: ['case', 'csgoItem'] })
export class CaseItem {
  @PrimaryKey({ type: 'uuid', defaultRaw: 'uuid_generate_v4()' })
  id: string;

  @Property({ type: 'double precision', columnType: 'double precision' })
  probability: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Case)
  case!: Case;

  @ManyToOne(() => CsgoItem, { cascade: [Cascade.REMOVE] })
  csgoItem!: CsgoItem;
}
```

When trying to insert a duplicate (based on the combination of case and csgItem, mikroORM allows me to do this. How can I make the `@unique` decorator work with relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a schema feature, the ORM does not enforce it anyhow, so you probably have out-of-sync schema - in other words, the unique constraint is not created.

Try running `npx mikro-orm schema:update --run`, or even better, adopt migrations if it's something more than just a toy project.

Few notes about the code you provided:

- `probability` is double, so it will be mapped to `string`, not `number`, as you can't fit a double into JS number
- no need to specify `type` and `columnType` together, not when you provide the same value in there
- the `cascade: [Cascade.REMOVE]` is probably not doing what you think, that is app-level cascading and means that when you delete the owning entity (CaseItem), its relations (marked with `Cascade.REMOVE`) will be removed too - this is the opposite of `onDelete: 'cascade'`, which I guess you want instead (so when the target is removed - the `CsgoItem` entity - the owner (so `Case`) will be removed too